# AWS Airflow Add provider - MongoDB

Tags: airflow, mwaa

I'm new in the AWS Airflow.
I have unmanaged Airflow on AWS ec2 instance which I want to move to the managed one.
When I went over the managed Airflow I saw there is missing provider for MongoDB.
How can I add it to the "connection type" drop down?
I couldn't found any wizard for guide me in this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to install the MongoDB provider package for the MWAA environment. Add the package `apache-airflow-providers-mongo` to `requirements.txt`. The MongoDB provider package is not installed by default in the MWAA environment.

References

1. [apache-airflow-providers-mongo (Airflow)](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-mongo/stable/index.html)
2. [Installing Python dependencies (MWAA)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/working-dags-dependencies.html)
3. [Default provider packages (GitHub)](https://github.com/aws/aws-mwaa-local-runner/blob/main/docker/config/requirements.txt)

Comment: PS D:\Airflow> pip install apache-airflow-providers-mongo
was successful but I still don't see Mongo in the provider's list on Dashboard http://localhost:8080/provider nor do I see the Mongo option in the Connection Type....Note I am running airflow as a docker container on Windows machine